# Is Riemann–Lebesgue lemma valuble in $L2(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: fourier-analysis, lebesgue-integral, harmonic-analysis, hardy-spaces

If $f\in L_1$ on $\mathbb{R}$, that is to say, if the Lebesgue integral of $|f|$ is finite, then the Fourier transform of $f$ satisfies
$$\hat{f}(z):= \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x)e^{-izx} dx \rightarrow 0, \text{when}~\, |z| \rightarrow \infty.  $$
This result is known as Riemann–Lebesgue lemma. I was wondering if this result is also true for  $f\in L_2$ on $\mathbb{R}$, that is, the Lebesgue integral of $|f|^2$ is finite. Can anybody help me?

Comment: $\hat{f}$ is not defined pointwise for a general $L^2$ function. For $f\in L^2$, you can define $\hat{f}$ as $\lim_{R\rightarrow\infty}\widehat{(\chi_{[-R,R]}f)}$, where the limit exists in $L^2$. This is a limit of Fourier transforms of $L^1$ functions, but the result is not defined pointwise.

Comment: @TrialAndError Exactly what does "defined pointwise" mean here? In fact if $f\in L^2$ then the Fourier transforms of $\chi_{[-R,R]}f$ _do_ converge almost everywhere to $\hat f$ - this is a hugely non-trivial theorem of Carleson...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich : The Lebesgue space $L^2$ consists of equivalence classes of functions that are equal a.e., and point values have no meaning. Moreover, a set of measure zero is enough to spoil any limit at any finite or infinite point.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since there is a Fourier inversion formula on $L^2$, it means that every $L^2$ function is a Fourier transform of some $L^2$ function. So if every such Fourier transform converged to zero at infinity, it would mean that every $L^2$ function does too.

But this is obviously not the case without regularity assumptions on the function.

Comment: Strong regularity assumptions in fact: even smoothness is not sufficient. (Though you should be careful here, because the Fourier transform on $L^2$ is defined by extension, not really through an integral. That is, you define it on $L^1 \cap L^2$ and then extend by continuity to all of $L^2$.)

Comment: Yes, more like uniform continuity, or stuff like that.

Comment: No, uniform continuity is not nearly enough to make an $L^2$ function tend to $0$ at infinity.

Comment: Ah no you're right, I was confusing with $L^1$ functions. Something like $1/2$-Hölder, then, I guess.

Comment: Can you find a counter example of an $L_2$ function whose Fourier transform has its limit in infinity different then 0 ?

Comment: Wait. I lied. _Uniform_ continuity _is_ enough, sorry.

Comment: @IgorDuffPereira Certainly not. If an $L^2$ function _has_ a limit at infinity that limit must obviously be zero. But a typical $L^2$ function simply does not have a limit at infinity.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich If you were responding to me, $1/2$-Hölder neither implies or is implied by any smoothness condition.

Comment: Well, note first that I've retracted my comments here. Not that it matters, but most people I think would say that a Holder condition _is_ a "smoothness condition". Silly to debate this without a definition of "smoothness condition"...

Comment: What led me astray is that no amount of _pointwise_ smoothness is enough. But a minimal amount of _uniform_ smoothness suffices.

Comment: @IgorDuffPereira In any case, if you want a function $f$ that is $L^2$ and whose Fourier transform does not converge at infinity, just take $f=\hat{g}$ where $g$ is a $L^2$ function that does not converge at infinity (I don't have a closed formula in mind, but take a function that does little bumps of width $1/n^2$ and height $1$).

Comment: what do you mean by  "regularity assumptions on the function."@CaptainLama